# overwrite all window.open _self with _blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I'm tring to use a website that overwrites all its links with a `javascript:window.open("/page.html","_self")`, which is extremely annoying, since I can't open several tabs.

Is there a way to overwrite all instances of `javascript:window.open("..","_self")` with `javascript:window.open("..","_blank")` with a browser extension?

Comment: Does it work when you use incognito tabs?

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the open function:

```
(function(window, open) {
    window.open = function(url) {
        open.call(window, url, '_blank');
    };
})(window, window.open);
```

That way it will always open new window.

You can create bookmark to modify opened page:

```
javascript:(function(window, open) {window.open = function(url) {open.call(window, url, '_blank');};})(window, window.open);
```

Use this as the URL of the bookmark and click it every time you load the page and before clicking any links.

Alternatively, you can write this code directly into the debug console, or use a browser plugin that can append it for you. *I don't use such plugins so I can't recommend any suitable.*